# Need the footer at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my website , I cannot figure out why the footer does not go down.

[image: picture of what i mean]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y3yh6vuo/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y3yh6vuo/1/

Comment: We cannot help you very well without seeing your code, please post it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:fixed` is your friend. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3yh6vuo/2/):

I just updated this CSS block:

```
.footer-id{
    padding-top:1%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

With that rules above I told the browser to fill the full with and to put it non scrolling to the buttom.